# azure virtual machine operations

Tags: python, azure

I am new to azure.I am learning azure python sdk and have some doubts.

1. I am not using any credentials to log in azure account and still can access 
   VM's in subscription in my code below, how?
2. I am trying to get list of all VM's using `list_all()` which is present in azure doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2018_10_01.operations.virtualmachinesoperations?view=azure-python#list-all-custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-
   , How can i get list of VM's or how to iterate over `VirtualMachinePaged object` return by `list_all()` to get list of VM's?
3. When i tried to print name of VM using `#print(client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group_name='GSLab', vm_name='GSLabVM2'))` i got error `Resource group 'GSLab' could not be found.`
   , i checked and sure that name of resource group in 'GSLab', so why am i getting this error?

Here is my code, Thank you and please suggest any other source for better understanding of these concepts if possible.

```
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_auth_file
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

client = get_client_from_auth_file(ComputeManagementClient)
#print(client)

vmlist = client.virtual_machines.list_all()
print(vmlist)
for vm in vmlist:
    print(vm.name)

print(client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group_name='GSLab', vm_name='GSLabVM2'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1:** You get the credentials from the Authentication file that you set and the service principal is in it.

**Q2:** You just need to delete the `print(vmlist)` and then everything is OK.

**Q3:**

The code:

```
client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group_name='GSLab', vm_name='GSLabVM2')
```

The result will like this:

[image]

So you need to check that if the resource group 'GSLab' really exist in the subscription you have set in the Authentication file.

Comment: Thanks, problem was with the resource group, it wasn't there.

Comment: In other subscription or it does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

```
vmlist = client.virtual_machines.list_all()
for vm in vmlist:
    print(vm.name)
```

this code is correct and this one as well:

```
client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group_name='GSLab', vm_name='GSLabVM2')
```

if they both return nothing you authenticated to the wrong subscription, you need to auth to the proper subscription.

simple way to check you got some output:

```
vmlist.next().name
```

Comment: Might help as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-authenticate